# How can convert a range of numerical data to a particular categorical data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in this range in a negative float from -100 to 100, and i want change this data of this way:

```
from 0 to 1 - ss
from 1 to 2 - sm
from 2 to 3 - sa
> 3 s

from 0 to -1 - bs
from 1 to -2 - bm
from 2 to -3 - ba
< 3 b
```

How can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following solution:

```
import pandas as pd

y = pd.DataFrame({"Data": [1.1, 1.3, 2.5, 3.9, -0.7, -1.3, -2.6, -9]})


def change_func(x):
    if x <= -3:
        return "b"
    elif -3 < x <= -2:
        return "ba"
    elif -2 < x <= -1:
        return "bm"
    elif -1 < x <= 0:
        return "bs"
    elif 0 < x <= 1:
        return "ss"
    elif 1 < x <= 2:
        return "sm"
    elif 2 < x <= 3:
        return "sa"
    else:
        return "s"


y["New_Column"] = y["Data"].apply(lambda x: change_func(x))

# if you do not want new line you can do the following:
# instead of y["New_Column"] = y["Data"].apply(lambda x: change_func(x) let's do:
# y["Data"] = y["Data"].apply(lambda x: change_func(x))

print(y)
```

I hope it will help, let me know if issue is solved, feel free to ask questions.